# Error using mcode for importing Matlab code into LaTeX

Tags: luatex, packages, document-classes

I want to import import matlab code into my latex document:

Consider the following code:

```
 \documentclass[bibliography=totoc,toc=sectionentrywithdots,DIV=10, parskip=half, 12pt,           captions=tableheading]{scrartcl}   
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{german}
\usepackage[autostyle=true,german=quotes]{csquotes} 
\usepackage[top=2.5cm, bottom=3cm, left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\addto\captionsngerman{%
\renewcommand{\figurename}{Abb.}%
 \renewcommand{\tablename}{Tab.}%
 }
\usepackage[headsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage} 
 \pagestyle{scrheadings}

 \usepackage{booktabs}   
 \usepackage[singlespacing]{setspace}
 \usepackage{romanbar}
 \usepackage{subfig}
  \usepackage[breaklinks=true]{hyperref}
  \usepackage{amsthm,amsmath,amssymb}
  \usepackage{dsfont}
 \allowdisplaybreaks
 \newtheorem{satz}{Satz}
  \usepackage[framed,numbered,autolinebreaks,useliterate]{mcode}
 \lstset{breakatwhitespace=false} 
 \newtheorem{lem}{Lemma}

 \ohead{\headmark}
\automark{section} 


 \begin{document}

 \lstinputlisting[caption={My program }]{bsp.m}


 \end{document}
```

Using `\usepackage[framed,numbered,autolinebreaks,useliterate]{mcode}`,
`\lstset{breakatwhitespace=false}`,
and compiling with LualaTeX I get several warnings:

Font shape `TU/pcr/m/n' undefined(Font) using 'TU/lmr/m/n` instead

Some font shapes were not available, defaults substituted.

Is there a problem with another package?

Furthermore I get a real error:

`! String contains an invalid utf-8 sequence. p_1=zeros(1, t-2); %% Speicher f`

The reason is I use "ü". How can I fix that. Sorry I am a beginner at learning LaTeX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a good idea to try and remove all unnecessary packages from your MWE; this also can help in identifying package incompatibilities before posting on here. :)

Regardless, looking at the `mcode.sty` file, there doesn't appear to be any package options that are set at the package declaration. Removing these from your provided MWE, I compile correctly - I got none of the warnings you are getting above. The `mcode` package appears to simply set style configurations for the `listings` package which is what displays your code for you. If you want more customisation, I recommend you abandon the `mcode` package and work solely with `listings` - it is very powerful, has good documentation, and is not difficult to set up.

You haven't included your MATLAB code, so your MATLAB error I cannot help you with. Try replacing the character with a 'plain' variant, such as `ü` -> `u` - it is code, after all. LaTeX should have no problem parsing the unicode characters.

For completeness, here's the code:

```
 \documentclass[bibliography=totoc,toc=sectionentrywithdots,DIV=10, parskip=half, 12pt,           captions=tableheading]{scrartcl}   
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{german}
\usepackage[autostyle=true,german=quotes]{csquotes} 
\usepackage[top=2.5cm, bottom=3cm, left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\addto\captionsngerman{%
\renewcommand{\figurename}{Abb.}%
 \renewcommand{\tablename}{Tab.}%
 }
\usepackage[headsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage} 
 \pagestyle{scrheadings}

 \usepackage{booktabs}   
 \usepackage[singlespacing]{setspace}
 \usepackage{romanbar}
 \usepackage{subfig}
  \usepackage[breaklinks=true]{hyperref}
  \usepackage{amsthm,amsmath,amssymb}
  \usepackage{dsfont}
 \allowdisplaybreaks
 \newtheorem{satz}{Satz}
 \usepackage{mcode} % removed package options causing errors
 \lstset{breakatwhitespace=false} 
 \newtheorem{lem}{Lemma}

 \ohead{\headmark}
\automark{section} 


 \begin{document}

 \lstinputlisting[caption={My program }]{bsp.m}


 \end{document}
```

and output (given some arbitrary MATLAB code):
[image]

Comment: Sorry for the late anwser. It worked. I also tried your recommended package. It works good. Thank you very much.